# How do I write the units for this answer?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, torque

If the force (at 90∘ to the lever arm) applied is 15 N and it is applied at 2.0 m from the pivot point (point of rotation), what is the torque on the lever?

Is it 30.0 N/m?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remember better how it works, you can just tell yourself that units follow the same operations as numbers. You obviously knew you had to do a product to get "30", now do the same with units. (as Danu is implying)

Comment: I got it, than you.

Answer (score 2):

You should think about the definition of torque: $$ \vec \tau = \vec{r}\times \vec F\implies \tau =rF\sin\theta$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec r$ and $\vec F$, the second equation refers to the magnitude of all quantities. If the units of $F$ are Newtons, and the units of $r$ are meters, then what should the units of $\tau$ be? Remember that angles are dimensionless, so $\sin\theta$ doesn't 'contribute' any units.